# double iframe problem

Tags: html

I have a page with 2 iframes, that consists of 3 files. The second iframe has one form inside, like this:

Page where user access(http://domain1.com/index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe name="ifr1" src="http://domain2.com/index.html" width="800" height="1000" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Page of domain2.com/index.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <iframe name="ifr2" src="http://domain3.com/form.html" width="400" height="400" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Page of domain3.com/form.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method='post' action='http://domain3.com/check.php' target='_parent' id='cform'>
    <input type="text" name="inp1">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

So, when user accesses to domain1.com/index.html, the result html becomes:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe name="ifr1" src="http://domain2.com/index.html" width="800" height="1000" scrolling="no">
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <iframe name="ifr2" src="http://domain3.com/form.html" width="400" height="400" scrolling="no">
             <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
             <form method='post' action='http://domain3.com/check.php' target='_parent' id='cform'>
                 <input type="text" name="inp1">
                 <input type="submit" value="send">
             </form>
             </body>
             </html>
        </iframe>
        </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user submits the form, i want to load the http://domain3.com/check.php content in the iframe named ifr1, but when the form is submitted, it loads the check.php content in a new window/tab.

I changed the domain of check.php and I copied it in domain2 to check if it works, and it does. Does it mean that is wrong to send a form content to a different domain? Does someone have any idea about it?

Thanks a lot! : )

Comment: Is this consistent across different browsers?

Comment: different browsers? I'm using Firefox for the whole test.

Answer (score 0):

iframes arent that usefull anymore for pulling in several files.  Looks like all you have is a form and a form check.  You can convert the code you have into php and use include() vs iframe.

take a gander at some [php tutorials](http://w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

What does your check file do?